# Categorical plots

Tags: python, dataframe, plot

Trying to create bar for category data but not working if categories increases.
Providing sample data and code i tried.

```
Name    Cat num
V   SS  1
V   SC  1
N   SC  1
Y   AD  14
Y   AC  1
I   SC  1
C   SC  1
B   SU  1
G   AC  8
G   AD  1
W   SC  2
Z   SC  1
D   SC  1
O   AD  4
O   RD  4
A   SC  1
P   AC  1
P   AS  1
P   AU  1
X   SU  2
J   DT  4
F   SC  1
M   SS  2
R   SS  1
S   AD  6
E   SC  1
H   SS  1
K   DT  2
L   AC  3
Q   SS  1
T   SS  1
U   AB  4

dt = df.groupby(['Cat','Name'],as_index=False)['num'].sum()

colors = plt.cm.Reds(np.linspace(0, 1, 26))[enter image description here][1]

dt.groupby(['Cat','Name'])['num'].sum().unstack().plot(kind='bar',color=colors)
```

Answer (score 0):

One format that works pretty well with what you're trying to do is the catplot from seaborn.

If I'm interpreting correctly, this code may be your ticket:

`import seaborn as sns
 sns.catplot(data=df, x='Name', y='num', hue='Cat', estimator=sum, kind='bar')`

"hue='Cat'" will assign a different color for each category you're trying to plot.

Read more on capabilities and parameters here: [seaborn.catplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html)

Comment: Thanks it works, but issue is i have 265 unique categories. it is not able to handle when i use all categories.